# Google cloud platform (GCP): mounting multiple volumes kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am setting up a container through Google cloud platform (GCP) kubernetes engine. I have a requirement to mount multiple volumes as the containers are created that way. These volume have to be persistent and hence I went with an NFS approach. I have a VM where NFS service is running and it exports couple of directories.

I am giving yaml sample files below.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-branch
  labels:
    component: myapp-branch
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: myapp-branch
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: myprivatekey
      containers:
        - name: myapp-branch
          image: mydockerrepo/myapp/webapp:6.6
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "while :; do echo '.'; sleep 100 ; done"]
          env:
          - name: myapp_UID
            value: "1011"
          - name: myapp_GID
            value: "1011"
          - name: myapp_USER 
            value: "myapp_branch"
          - name: myapp_XMS_G
            value: "1"
          - name: myapp_XMX_G
            value: "6"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /mypath1/path1
            name: pvstorestorage
          - mountPath: /mypath2/path2
            name: mykeys
      volumes:
      - name: pvstorestorage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: standalone
      - name: mykeys
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: conf
```

**PVAndPVC.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: standalone
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.2.1.6
    path: "/exports/path1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: standalone
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: conf
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.2.1.6
    path: "/exports/path2"

---    

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: conf
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

after applying them, I see that both the volume mounts of container (/mypath1/path1 and /mypath2/path2) are mounted to same mount point of nfs (/exports/path2, the second one). This is happening with persistentVolumeClaim, I tried EmptyDir, its working fine.
If any one tried this approach and know the solution, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you do `kubectl get pvc` to see which PVs the PVCs are bound to?

Comment: @weibeld The binding is fine between PV and PVC, the problem is when I mount the container directory to the persistent volume. Please see my comment below

Comment: Both PVCs are bound to the correct PV? But when you mount them in the container, suddenly one of the PVCs uses another PV?

Comment: @weibeld yes that is correct. kubectl get pv and kubectl get pvc are perfectly fine. Container mounting is going wrong, some how its not able to match, randomly it picks one claim and mounts it to both the volumes of container. When I look at df, 10.2.1.6:/exports/path2 is mounted to /mypath1/path1 and 10.2.1.6:/exports/path2 is mounted to /mypath1/path2/. /export/path2 is mounted to both the volumes of container.

Comment: Apparently, multiple mounting does not work at all if the mount end point is in the same nfs server. However, if the mount points are in different nfs servers, it seems to work. Not sure if some one ever tried to use multiple mount points.

Answer (score 1):

You must add a rule in your PVC (PersistentVolumeClaim) definitions to make them match their correct respective PV (PersistentVolume).

Having the same name is not enough.

Change your PV and PVC definitions into something like (untested) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: standalone
  labels:
    type: standalone
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.2.1.6
    path: "/exports/path1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: conf
  labels:
    type: conf
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.2.1.6
    path: "/exports/path2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: standalone
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: standalone
---    

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: conf
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: conf
```

(typically, I added a metadata.labels.type in PVs and a spec.selector.matchLabels in PVCs)

Also, use `kubectl get pv` and `kubectl get pvc` to see how it is working and ease debugging

Comment: thank you for your response. I should have mentioned this earlier, the binding of PV and PVC are going well, when I describe the volume, I could see that the claim is bound to correct volume (of my NFS server). But when I execute the deployment, which actually mounts container directory to the persistent volume, that is going bad. Randomly, one single persistent volume is mounted to all the directories of container.

Comment: df -k 
10.2.1.6:/exports/path2 /mypath1/path1
10.2.1.6:/exports/path2 /mypath1/path2